# xpath to the send whatsapp messages stopped working, updated xpath not recognized

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have been using this code to send multiple messages to a list of whatsApp users and it has worked for a while. But it has stopped working recently.

i'm getting this error message before the message is sent.
`selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]"}`

I thought to update the xpath:
`'//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button/span'` it used to be
`'//*@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]'`

But I still get the same error.

I'm currently trying to use this code.
`navegador.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/button/span').send_keys(Keys.SEND)`

Any hints as to what happened?

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are using absolute xpath which got impacted may be due to any changes in UI. so It is recommended to use Relative(Dynamic) xpath for locator.

You can use selectors hub extension which is available for all major browsers to get dynamic xpath, You can refer below video :
[Selectors Hub Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jV84DRg96qs)